# Adding labels to 3D scatterplot not working

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I wish to add text labels to a 3D scatterplot in matplotlib, but it either doesn't work at all or it collapses the axes into a mess. I've tried all the workarounds I can find, but they don't seem to do the job. Here's what I've done so far.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x_value': [0.58245011499999999,0.58875,0.58571373199999999,0.57505909399999999], 'y_value': [0.575939804, 0.53125, 0.574922673, 0.56629390800000001], 'z_value': [0.37844187799999995,0.14374999999999999, 0.38144978899999998, 0.4012994879999999], 'text_name':['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3', 'text_4']})


fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(data['x_value'], data['y_value'], data['z_value'], c = data.index,  cmap = cm.summer, s=60)

points = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    points.append((data['x_value'][i], data['y_value'][i], 
    data['z_value'][i], data['text_name'][i]))

ax.set_xlabel('X_VALUES')
ax.set_ylabel('Y_VALUES')
ax.set_zlabel('Z_VALUES')

ax.view_init(34, 200)

plt.title('MY PLOT')

for i in range(len(points)):
    ax.text3D(points[i][0], points[i][1], points[i][2], points[i][3], zdir= 
    (1, 1, 1))

plt.show()
```

The result of this exercise, however, is null––no point labels are visible:

[image: Plot with no labels]

However, when I add the following lines above `plt.show()`, I get the labels, but all messed up and the consequent error message:

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False) 
### This loop included to forestall known problem with plt.tight_layout() collapsing axes that nevertheless happens anyway.

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Plot bad labels]

> The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate
>   all axes decorations

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The tight_layout problem might be a consequence of the missing labels in the normal view. If you want to provide a [mcve] one can sure find out what's wrong ther.

Comment: Fair point. I've added a truncated version of the dataframe (but with actual values) to allow for this. Hope it helps!

Comment: The plot I get when correcting for all the errors in the code is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcNaI.png). The tight_layout problem is less pronounced in version 3.0.1. It should not occur in version 3.0.2.

Comment: Apologies, I should have tested that code first; it's fixed now. I also obtained the plot you did, but I now face the mystery of why my original dataframe didn't work, which isn't much larger than this one. My labels are longer in my actual data; could that be the issue?

Comment: It could be. What happens when you add `rotation_mode="anchor"` to the text?

Comment: No change with rotation_mode = "anchor". Moreover, when I cut down my labels to singe characters the same problems emerge. Baffled now!

Comment: Hard to judge from the outside. If you are able to create an example where the issue occurs that you can share here, one can further look into it.